# Telegram bot api: disable push notifications for sendMessage

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I use telegram bot api to send messages to a channel. I need to disable push notifications for Android and IOS, but when I pass `disable_notification = true`, I don't get notifications for my desktop client, but my Android and IOS devices get push notifications (without sound).

Is it possible to disable push notifications for Android and IOS for telegram bot api and method send message?

P.S: I use PHP for sending messages to telegram.

Answer (score 2):

Now it's possible to pass `disable_notification` to `sendMessage` method -- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

`bot.sendMessage('chat_id', 'text', {disable_notification: true}`

Answer (score 0):

No, the user should mute the bot.
`disable_notification` is only for channels.

From Bot API:

> Sends the message [silently](https://telegram.org/blog/channels-2-0#silent-messages). Users will receive a notification
>   with no sound.

The link refers to the channels